# How to solve a polynomial of the form y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d using the incremental algorithm in computer graphics

Tags: algorithms, graphics, polynomials

I am studying Computer Graphics and need to design an incremental algorithm for solving the polynomial $y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, and then implement that in OpenGL. The input will be the values of $a, b,c,d$ and the desired output is a *line/curve* to be drawn. The values of $x$ would be in the range $1\leq x\leq100$. The algorithm needs to be very efficient hence I am required to use only *addition* operation, as multiplication is less efficient.

It would be similar to [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOl-JUTLyPg), but here the polynomial to be considered is the one given above. I have searched a lot on the Internet but cannot find the required solution, because most of the examples solve the equation $y = mx+b$.

Can anyone kindly guide me how to solve it or which method should be applied to solve it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by solving it?  What are the inputs, and what is the desired output?  Are you given the value of $a,b,c,d,y$ and you want to find a value $x$ such that $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=y$?  Can you edit the question to clarify?  Also, what do you mean by "not using multiplication"?  I don't even know what that means.  What does that mean, and where does that requirement come from?  Is there some context that would help us understand your needs?

Comment: @D.W. I have edited my question. The inputs will the values of a, b, c, d, and the output would be a line to be drawn. And for making it efficient, we cannot use multiplication but can use addition only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have f(x). Let g(x) = f(x+1) - f(x). Let h(x) = g(x+1) - g(x). Let k(x) = h(x+1) - h(x). It turns out that k(x) is a constant.

Calculate f(x), g(x), h(x) and k(x) for x = 1. Then you calculate f(x+1) = f(x) + g(x), g(x+1) = g(x) + h(x), h(x+1) = h(x) + k(x), and k(x) is a constant.

Comment: It seems like FDX (forward differences) technique, which of course is answer.